# Sort 2D Array Row's Depend on the last column

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to Write a Program in c++ that swap the row but my code only sort the element of the array.
For example:
I made a array of 3*5.
I input data as follows

```
1 2 3 4 10
5 6 7 8 26
9 1 2 3 15
```

Now I want to swap the rows by ascending order depends on the last column.i.e.

```
5 6 7 8 26
9 1 2 3 15
1 2 3 4 10
```

My code Only Sort the Row form left to Right.

```
int arr[3][5], sum, temp;
for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    sum=0;
    for(int j =0; j<4; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter "<<j+1<<" Number of "<<i+1<<" Student";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
        sum = sum + arr[i][j];
    }
    arr[i][4]=sum;
}

for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout<<"----------------"<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j<4;j++)
    {
        for(int k =0;k<4;k++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j]<arr[i][k])
            {
                temp=arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j]=arr[i][k];
                arr[i][k]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
    for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j =0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question?

Comment: `swap the rows by ascending order` I'm not sure what this means. Do you mean sort the rows by ascending order?

Comment: @Neil Yes....
But I Can not able to do this.Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Why not use a `std::map<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>`?  Then  it will "auto-sort" for you if you make the last element in your array the key element in the map.  http://ideone.com/0uRSZd

Comment: This is what I would do. Although you say ascending but your example is descending so I'm confused by that. http://ideone.com/qZEXux

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have to do this by 2D Array.

Comment: You could always swat a fly with a sledgehammer and use `std::qsort` ([see it live](http://ideone.com/VGW0Zz)). Arrays of arrays of natives is one of the few places it still makes sense to use in an otherwise post-apocalyptic `std::sort` world (which you could still do with `std::array<int,5> arr[3];` ([see it live](http://ideone.com/GxTYks))).

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not of significant concern, just use the same idea as Bubble sort.

Compare last column element between each pair of rows, and if not in order swap the rows. This can be done with a loop and a temporary variable.

```
if(matrix[i][cols-1] > matrix[j][cols-1])
{
    int temp ;
    for(int k = 0; k < cols; ++k)
    {
        temp = matrix[i][k] ;
        matrix[i][k] = matrix[j][k] ;
        matrix[j][k] = temp ;
    }
}
```

Since you are using C++, you can use `std::array` if your matrix has fixed size rows and columns. i.e.

```
std::array<std::array<int, colums>, rows> matrix ;
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2e856abf5eee250) is a working example which uses `std::swap` to do the swapping of rows. The sorting routine is essentially the bubble sort.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        if(matrix[j][cols-1] > matrix[i][cols-1])
            std::swap(matrix[i], matrix[j]);
```

Comment: In C++11 you can use `std::swap` on arrays.

Comment: Added the `std::swap` part along with `std::array`.

Comment: That's good, my only suggestion is to use constants or template parameters on your full example, to make the code more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your answer:

```
int arr[3][5], sum, temp;
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << j + 1 << " Number of " << i + 1 << " Student";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
        sum = sum + arr[i][j];
    }
    arr[i][4] = sum;
}
cout << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "----------------" << endl << endl;
int tmp[5],i,j,k;
for ( i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j<3; j++)
    {

            if (arr[j][4]<arr[i][4])
            {
                for ( k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
                    int t = arr[i][k];
                    arr[i][k] = arr[j][k];
                    arr[j][k] = t;
                }

            }

    }
}


for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```